# Problema al pedir una opción por teclado mediante PYTHON

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy empezando con python, y estoy intentando hacer un "Piedras, papel y tijeras" mediante funciones. Pero por alguna razón, a la hora de pedir la opción al usuario (0 para piedra, 1 para papel y 2 para tijeras) me sigue pidiendo dicho numero, aunque ya se haya introducido.

---

Dejaré el código completo ya que no es muy largo

```
import random as ran


def inicializa():
    global opciones
    opciones = ['Piedra', 'Papel', 'Tijera\n']
    maquina_opcion()
    humano_opcion()
    logica()


def maquina_opcion():
    opcion_maquina = opciones[ran.randrange(0, 3)]
    return opcion_maquina


def humano_opcion():
    opcion_humano = opciones[int(input("¿Piedra, papel, o tijera?\n"))]
    return opcion_humano



def logica():
    # Handles the situation where the machine loses or a draw
    if maquina_opcion() == humano_opcion():
        print('Empate')
    if maquina_opcion() == 0 and humano_opcion() == 1 or maquina_opcion() == 1 and humano_opcion() == 2\
    or maquina_opcion() == 2 and humano_opcion() == 0:
        print('Machine wins. She choosed'+maquina_opcion()+'And you choosed'+humano_opcion())

    # Handles the situatuion where the human loses
    if humano_opcion() == 0 and maquina_opcion() == 1 or humano_opcion() == 1 and maquina_opcion() == 2\
    or humano_opcion() == 2 and humano_opcion() == 0:
        print('Human wins. You choosed'+humano_opcion()+' and the machine choosed'+maquina_opcion())
def main():
    inicializa()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Por pantalla saldría el siguiente error:**

```
¿Piedra, papel, o tijera?
1 [Es el numero introducido por teclado]
¿Piedra, papel, o tijera?
2 [Es el numero introducido por teclado]
¿Piedra, papel, o tijera?
3 [Es el numero introducido por teclado]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alumno/Dropbox/PHYTON/Ahorcado.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/alumno/Dropbox/PHYTON/Ahorcado.py", line 36, in main
    inicializa()
  File "C:/Users/alumno/Dropbox/PHYTON/Ahorcado.py", line 9, in inicializa
    logica()
  File "C:/Users/alumno/Dropbox/PHYTON/Ahorcado.py", line 32, in logica
    if humano_opcion() == 0 and maquina_opcion() == 1 or humano_opcion() == 1 and maquina_opcion() == 2\
  File "C:/Users/alumno/Dropbox/PHYTON/Ahorcado.py", line 18, in humano_opcion
    opcion_humano = opciones[int(input("¿Piedra, papel, o tijera?\n"))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes errores importantes en la lógica:

- Llamas a las funciones encargadas de retornar la opción de la "máquina" y del "humano" en tu función `inicializa` pero estas opciones que retornan jamás son asignadas a una variable por lo que simplemente no hacen nada en realidad.
- En tu función `lógica` llamas a las funciones anteriores de nuevo y repetidamente en los condicionales. Cada vez que haces `humano_opcion()` **estas llamando de nuevo (ejecutando) la función**, ésta por tanto pide una nueva entrada y retorna la opción, no usas las opciones generadas al llamarlas en `inicializa` como creo que pretendías.

  Con `if maquina_opcion() == humano_opcion()`: llamas a cada funciona al hacer la comparación, si el condicional no se cumple pasas al siguiente `if` donde se **vuelve a llamar la funciones** en `if maquina_opcion() == 0 and humano_opcion() == 1`, si no se cumplen se vuelven a llamar para comprobar el siguiente `or`... Cada vez que las funciones son llamadas generan y piden una nueva entrada retornando nuevas opciones... Por otro lado, las funciones que retornan la opción elegida retornan una cadeana ("Piedra"/"Papel"/"Tijera") no enteros, por lo que `if maquina_opcion() == 0` no tiene sentido, debería ser `if maquina_opcion() == "Piedra"`
- Deberías usar una construcción `if-elif-else` en vez de varios `if` concatenados. Si se cumple el primer `if` (empate) no tiene sentido evaluar nada más. Lo mismo si  sabemos que la máquina gana, tampoco tiene sentido evaluar las condiciones con las que el humano gana.
- Considera pasar los valores como argumentos a las funciones en vez de usar variables globales. Por norma general evita usar variables globales si existe una forma alternativa que te permite hacer lo mismo sin penalizaciones. Suelen ser fruto de errores y dificultan la legibilidad del código.

Sin tocar demasiado tu código podrías hacer algo así:

```
import random as ran


def inicializa():
    opciones = ['Piedra', 'Papel', 'Tijera']
    maquina_opt = maquina_opcion(opciones)
    humano_opt = humano_opcion(opciones)
    logica(maquina_opt, humano_opt)


def maquina_opcion(opciones):
    opcion_maquina = opciones[ran.randrange(0, 3)]
    return opcion_maquina


def humano_opcion(opciones):
    opcion_humano = opciones[int(input("¿Piedra, papel, o tijera?\n"))]
    print(opcion_humano)
    return opcion_humano



def logica(maq_opc, hum_opc):
    if maq_opc == hum_opc:
        print('Empate')
        
    elif (maq_opc == "Piedra" and hum_opc =="Tijera") or \
         (maq_opc == "Papel" and hum_opc == "Piedra") or \
         (maq_opc == "Tijera" and hum_opc == "Papel"):

        print('Machine wins. She choosed {} and you choosed {}.'.format(maq_opc, hum_opc))
        
    else:
        print('Human wins. You choosed {} and the machine choosed {}'.format(hum_opc, maq_opc))
        
def main():
    inicializa()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Deberías considerar validar también la entrada del usuario para evitar una excepción si no ingresa una opción válida. Una forma de generar un menú numerado a partir de una lista cualquiera de opciones y que valide la entrada puede ser:

```
def humano_opcion(opciones):
    num_ops = [str(n+1) for n in range(len(opciones))] 
    menu = "\n".join(("Elige una opción:",
                     *("  {}. {}".format(i, opt) for i, opt in zip(n_ops, opciones)),
                     ">>> "))
    
    while True:
        opt = input(menu)
        if opt in n_ops:
            break
        print("Opción no válida.")
            
    return opciones[int(opt) - 1]
```

Posiblemente te estas complicando demasiado para hacer esto, en un afán de dividir el código en funciones, se puede simplificar bastante pero como supongo que tratas practicar el uso de funciones no he querido modificar la lógica que sigues. .

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, quería practicar las funciones y he decidido hacerlo con este ejemplo, mis dieces.